# Resizing the facebook iframe to fit smaller content?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

From my research it seems as if this is a re-occuring problem. I'm using the following code to resize the iframe, it currently works... that is it resizes the iframe to fit larger content, however it won't shrink back again!

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    /* Init fb Resize window */
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);
    FB.init({
        appId:'<?php echo Yii::app()->params['fbAppId']; ?>',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
    });
  };
</script>
```

The code is positioned at the very end of the html file, before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not logical to call **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);** before you call **FB.init()**

Also you should not call **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);** in **window.fbAsyncInit**

Here is a proper example

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : js_fb_app_id,
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth   : true          
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
});
```

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). This way you can be sure that the page is resized when [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is loaded, not before that. This way you can place your code anywhere on the page.

You set **FB.Canvas.setAutoResize** to 700 ms. Do you have any particular reason to do so ? The default value is 100ms

Comment: I've tried your code, it has the same outcome. The iframe will grow, but not shrink. I think i've found the solution now, it involved manually shrinking the iframe.

Comment: FB.Canvas.setAutoResize uses setInterval() and recalculate the page height every XX ms. Not shrinking the page means that JS cannot get the iframe height. This may be due some sort of "position: absolute" or float in the HTML(CSS) code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to call setSize() once after the page is fully loaded, like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize({width:760,height:document.body.offsetHeight});
}
</script>
```

You don't actually need FB.init unless you are using the SDK for other things as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing exactly the same issue with my app on https://fb.pienternet.be/overview for a few weeks now -- tried a lot of things but none of them work.. using setTimeout, using setSize manually, the new setAutoGrow, combinations of them... It happens when navigating within in the iframe from long to short pages , but also from short to long pages.

What does work for me is navigating to the pages using the parent URI; e.g. apps.facebook.com/pienternet/detail/5 ... I guess this is a bug in the SDK, will post this on the Facebook bugtracking platform too.

Two screenshots to make this clear:

- http://cl.ly/3t2U2i272G40110X3b0p (you can see the footer end in the black background)
- http://cl.ly/1n442j0w3i2W1f050W04 (you can see the content being cut off)

Comment: I've looked at how Zynga get around the problem. They use their own iFrame.